# Receive file using Bluetooth and wifi

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

Can Raspberry Pi receive files from mobile phones using Bluetooth and/or WiFi (at the same time, from multiple phones) without needing too much configuring? Will it need Bluetooth and WiFi modules separately or will it come with these in built? 
I know that we can plug in an USB stick in few devices and turn it into a file server but I need a device to act as more of a *receiver* rather than *server*. Any suggestion or even a small discussion of what anyone knows related to this is most welcome. :-)

Comment: As rav_k's answer hints, you have misunderstood the role of a server in [client-server software architecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_server).  It is NOT called "sender-receiver" architecture.  A server provides a service to a client.  That service may be to *receive* files, or to send files, or both.   The difference between server and client is that clients initiate contact with servers (to engage the service provided), whereas a server cannot initiate contact with a client.  It is possible for the same application to play either role depending on context.

Answer (score 2):

If Raspberry Pi needs to receive files it have to be configured as a server.

One method is to use ftp server and client.
RPi have to be connected (Ethernet or WiFi adapter) to the same network as mobile phones.

**Raspberry Pi**
To install ftp server, in Linux terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install proftpd
```

While installation you will be prompted to select mode, choose `standalone`

Server now works.
Without any changes, user *pi* (default password is `raspberry`) will have access to `/home/pi`.
If you want to change configuration file, you can do it using:

```
sudo nano /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf
```

**Android device**
You can use any ftp client.
I personally use [Total Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander) with [FTP Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.tcplugins.FTP).
Another good application is [AndFTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftp)

**Other mobile devices**
I don't know any ftp clients for other systems (iOS, BlackBerry...) but there should be plenty of them.